# What does '?' mean in this statement of C++?

Tags: c++

What is another way to rewrite this?
This function is called when the user says their number is higher in the program

```
virtual void higher() {
   //dont go above high
low = (getCurrentGuess() + 1 > high) ? high : getCurrentGuess() + 1;
seed = time(NULL);
}
```

Comment: it is an if statement.  `a = b ? c : d`  means `if (b) a=c; else a=d;`  It is called the ternary operator.  Here are three pages that might help: https://www.w3schools.com/cpp/cpp_conditions_shorthand.asp https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/conditional-or-ternary-operator-in-c-c/ https://www.tutorialspoint.com/c-cplusplus-ternary-operator   An example it is useful for is `bool x=false; printf("%s",x?"true":"false");`

Comment: This is called a ternary operator. You can simply use an if-else operation. But it does the same.